# Python nested a generator inside a if else nested in a return is possible?

Tags: python, generator, conditional-operator

I try to create a shorter algorithms to guess if a number is a prime-number or not

So there is the algorithms that I want to short

```
def is_premier(n):
    i=2
    while i < n and n%i !=0:
        i+=1
    return i==n
```

And there is what I try to do:

```
def is_prime_v3(n):
    return ("Non Prime" if n%i==0 else "Prime" for i in range(2,n))
```

But I don't know if this generator is correct or there is a way to get the string ?
My real interest is not the prime number algorith, I try to figure out if is it possible to get something
with this following structure ( return a if condition else b for x in range(n); and collect the answer a or b)

Thanks for answers

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You used a conditional expression (`a if cond else b`) correctly; it doesn't matter here that it's inside a generator expression.

Comment: However, your translation from `is_premier()` to `is_prime_v3)` is incorrect. You are generating a series of `"Non Prime"` and `"Prime"` strings with no filtering. E.g. `7` is prime, and so you generate the sequence `'Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime'`. `8` is not prime, but your function outputs `'Non Prime', 'Prime', 'Non Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't manage to translate the first function correctly, no.

- The function `is_premier()` returns a *single*  boolean value, while `is_prime_v3()` returns a generator of strings.
- The `is_prime_v3()` generator produces multiple `"Prime"` values for non-prime numbers, e.g. for `8`, the test `8 % 3 == 0` is false, so `"Prime"` is generated:

  ```py
  >>> list(is_prime_v3(8))
  ['Non Prime', 'Prime', 'Non Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime', 'Prime']
  ```

Using a conditional expression is the wrong tool here. The first function *stops early when a condition is met*, while your second loop never stops early, and only produces different values each iteration.

If you use a regular loop and `print()` calls instead of yielding, this is what is executed:

```py
for i in range(2, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        print("Non Prime")
    else:
        print("Prime")
```

That loop also never stops when `n % i == 0` is found.

Now, it *could* have been your goal to do so, to produce `Non Prime` and `Prime` strings. However, it is *easier* if you used booleans instead, so `True` and `False`.

Your first function could be described, in English, as doing this:

- Start `i` at 2
- as long as `i` is smaller than `n` and `n % i != 0` is true, add one to `i`.
- if `i` is equal to `n`, we have a prime number!

You could also use a `range()` for that, and then it becomes:

- Take `i` from the range 2 to `n` (not including `n`).
- if ever `n % i == 0` is true, this is not a prime number.
- if we never found a value for `i` where `n % i == 0`, we have a prime number!

In code that is:

```py
for i in range(2, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        return false
return true
```

For that kind of 'early exit' if a condition is met or not met, you can use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions. These work best with a generator, they test each value produced and return `true` or `false` *early* if the condition no longer holds.

E.g. for the case where *all* values of `i` must not be a divisor, you can use:

```py
def is_prime_generator(n):
    return all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, n))
```

Finally, your own attempt, `is_prime_v3()`, could be made to do the same, if used as a utility function, where we don't require that all `n % i != 0` tests are true, but that all strings are `'Prime'`:

```py
>>> all(s == 'Prime' for s in is_prime_v3(8))
False
>>> all(s == 'Prime' for s in is_prime_v3(7))
True
```

Comment: Detailed answer, but I think you meant `as long as i is smaller than n ` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Your direction is good, but your expression returns a series of strings instead of a single value.

Looking at your original code, it basically says: *if any number less than `n` divides `n` - return `False`. Otherwise `True`*.

So this directly translates to Python as:

```py
def is_prime(n):
    return not any(n%i == 0 for i in range(2,n))
```

Which is also equivalent to:

```py
def is_prime_v3(n):
    return all(n%i != 0 for i in range(2,n))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reproduce the same logic (i.e. `i` advances up to `n` stopping on first divisor), you could formulate it like this:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return "Prime" if next(i for i in range(2,n+1) if n%i == 0) == n else "Non Prime"
```

or you could let the next() function select the string for you:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return next(("Non Prime" for i in range(2,n) if n%i == 0),"Prime")
```